# MVC pass ids separated by "+" to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to have possibility to access action by the following URL type:

http://localhost/MyControllerName/MyActionName/Id1+Id2+Id3+Id4  etc.

and handle it in code in the following way:

```
public ActionResult MyActionName(string[] ids)
{
  return View(ids);
}
```

Comment: Actually I need: `code`public ActionResult MyActionName(int[] ids)
{
  return View(ids);
}`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all chose the following solution:

```cs
    public ActionResult Action(string id = "")
    {
        var ids = ParseIds(id);

        return View(ids);
    }

    private static int[] ParseIds(string idsString)
    {
        idsString = idsString ?? string.Empty;

        var idsStrings = idsString.Split(new[] { ' ', '+' });

        var ids = new List<int>();

        foreach (var idString in idsStrings)
        {
            int id;

            if (!int.TryParse(idString, out id))
                continue;

            if (!ids.Contains(id))
                ids.Add(id);
        }

        return ids.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

`+` is a reserved symbol in an url. It means white space. So to achieve what you are looking for you could write a custom model binder:

```
public class StringModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return value.AttemptedValue.Split(' ');
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

and then either register it globally for the `string[]` type or use the [`ModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public ActionResult MyActionName(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(StringModelBinder))] string[] ids
)
{
    return View(ids);
}
```

Obviously if you want to use an url of the form `/MyControllerName/MyActionName/Id1+Id2+Id3+Id4` that will bind the last part as an action parameter called `ids` you will have to modify the default route definition which uses `{id}`.

Comment: amazing answer darin, I really thought this was not possible!